# Error: template: inject:469: function "appendMultusNetwork" not defined

Tags: kubernetes, istio, istio-kiali, istio-sidecar

```
istioctl kube-inject \
--injectConfigFile inject-config.yaml \
--meshConfigFile mesh-config.yaml \
--valuesFile inject-values.yaml \
--filename samples/sleep/sleep.yaml \
| kubectl apply -f -
```

While trying to inject istio sidecar container manually to pod. I got error -

Error: template: inject:469: function "appendMultusNetwork" not defined

https://istio.io/latest/docs/setup/additional-setup/sidecar-injection/

Comment: What is your istio version? Have you changed anything in above configs? I have tried that example from documentation on my test cluster with istio 1.7.3 and everything worked just fine.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in comments I have tried to reproduce your issue on gke with istio 1.7.4 installed.

I've followed the documentation you mentioned and it worked without any issues.

---

1.Install istioctl and istio default profile

```
curl -sL https://istio.io/downloadIstioctl | sh -
export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.istioctl/bin
istioctl install
```

2.Create `samples/sleep` directory and create [sleep.yaml](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/istio/istio/release-1.7/samples/sleep/sleep.yaml), for example with vi.

3.Create local copies of the configuration.

```
kubectl -n istio-system get configmap istio-sidecar-injector -o=jsonpath='{.data.config}' > inject-config.yaml
kubectl -n istio-system get configmap istio-sidecar-injector -o=jsonpath='{.data.values}' > inject-values.yaml
kubectl -n istio-system get configmap istio -o=jsonpath='{.data.mesh}' > mesh-config.yaml
```

4.Apply it with istioctl kube-inject

```
istioctl kube-inject \
    --injectConfigFile inject-config.yaml \
    --meshConfigFile mesh-config.yaml \
    --valuesFile inject-values.yaml \
    --filename samples/sleep/sleep.yaml \
    | kubectl apply -f -
```

5.Verify that the sidecar has been injected

```
kubectl get pods
NAME                     READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
sleep-5768c96874-m65bg   2/2     Running   0          105s
```

---

So there are few things worth to check as it might might cause this issue::

- Could you please check if you executed all your commands correctly?
- Maybe you run older version of istio and you should follow older
  [documentation](https://istio.io/archive/)?
- Maybe you changed something in above local copies of the
  configuration and that cause the issue? If you did what exactly did you change?